# replace &amp; with & using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tr>
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Category"></a>Category</h3></td>
    <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldChoice">
    <td width="350" class="ms-formbody" id="SPFieldChoice" valign="top">
    <!-- FieldName="Category"
         FieldInternalName="Category"
         FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
      -->
        Health &amp; Fitness        
    </td>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
```

I need to replace `&amp;` with `&` using jQuery from `Health &amp; Fitness`. How can I do that.

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why? They render the same

Comment: `console.log($("<textarea/>").html('&amp;').text());` Is that what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using javascript string `.replace` function.

```
var el = $('#SPFieldChoice');
el.html(el.html().replace("&amp;", "&"));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/837m6gu4/)

Find td text and use replace .

```
$('td#SPFieldChoice').text().replace('&amp;','&')
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should not have the same IP for different

2) use `$('idOfYourNode').text().replace("&amp;", "&");`